# If there is no Google banner ad, display the start.io banner ad?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

> Sometimes there is no banner ad from Google and I want to take
> advantage of that empty space by displaying another ad from
> StarApp,
>  but I want to do this strictly when there is no banner ad
> from Google

### java

```
      StartAppSDK.init(this, (getResources().getString(R.string.ad_star)), false);
//        StartAppAd.showAd(this);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId (getResources().getString(R.string.admob_main));
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

### layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/admob_main">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <com.startapp.sdk.ads.banner.Banner
                    android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

> The code is working and everything is perfect, both appear but cover a
> large portion of the screen so:
>    I want a StarApp ad to appear if
> there is no ad in the Google banner and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

this way it can be possible

1. try to load admob

   public void showBannerADMOB() {

   ```
    bannerViewAdMob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (bannerViewAdMob == null)
        return;

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    bannerViewAdMob.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            bannerViewAdMob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            bannerViewAdMob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showBannerStartApp();
        }
    });
    bannerViewAdMob.loadAd(adRequest);
   ```

   }

as above call showBannerADMOB(), in that admob banner fails go for StartApp

```
public void showBannerStartApp() {

    relativeStartAppBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bannerViewAdMob.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //startAppBanner.loadAd(400,150);
    startAppBanner.setBannerListener(new BannerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveAd(View view) {
            startAppBanner.showBanner();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(View view) {
            Log.d("===", "onFailedToReceiveAd :: banner");
            relativeStartAppBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            startAppBanner.hideBanner();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onImpression(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}
```

layout for this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id"
    android:visibility="visible">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeStartAppBanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <com.startapp.sdk.ads.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way I have implemented, if admob will failed it will show StartApp.
Hope it work for you.... :)

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your answer, but regarding my codes, do I remove them and use the codes that you have set?

Comment: I hope the answer is according to my codes, I don't want something to go wrong and I lose ads completely

Comment: you can just comment your code and add my code. In my app ads are working not any issue till the time. Don't remove your code just comment it and add my code. Hopefully it will work. Let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: You can laugh at me, I don't know how to put them, I'm a beginner and a new learner, please answer according to my codes please.

Comment: put xml as i mentioned in answer, and in your activity just call "showBannerADMOB()". Also make sure you have added findViewById for both ad view from xml